# Optimised query to select document and possible annotations

Tags: mysql, join

I have a database of small documents which users can view and annotate. Their annotations are not public. I'm looking to optimise a single query to read the document and annotations for the current user.

Originally I tried this:

```
SELECT content,select_start,select_end,select_colour
FROM documents
LEFT OUTER JOIN annotations
USING (document_id)
WHERE document_id=<some_document_id_here> AND (user_id=<some_user_id_here> or user_id IS NULL)
```

But it failed to return a document if another user had added annotations. So I'm now using this:

```
SELECT content,select_start,select_end,select_colour
FROM documents A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT document_id,select_start,select_end,select_colour
    FROM annotations
    WHERE user_id=<some_user_id_here>
) B
ON A.document_id = B.document_id
WHERE A.document_id=<some_document_id_here>
```

which works, but the inner select statement could create quite a sizeable temporary table. I'd like to know if there's a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've been able to come up with is to limit the size of the temporary table as much as possible by changing the inner WHERE to:

```
WHERE user_id=<some_user_id_here> AND document_id=<some_document_id_here>
```

It means the document ID has to be repeated in the statement, but at least means that the inner table is small, and pretty much guaranteed to be in-memory.